# Does confirm() work in android mobile on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, mobile, confirm

I have a confirm  request embedded in my .js file which requires user confirm before answering a call. Although it works fine in desktop Chrome but nothing happens in Mobile chrome (android)? This is the website http://webtest1.parseapp.com/ , but you need to create a login and add a friend and click on their name on the left to be able to call them if you need to test. This might be as simple as this only works on desktop as I am new to Mobile chrome. It is also a peer to peer services if you need to know.

```
 if (confirm("Answer call?") == true) {
    call.answer(window.localStream);
     step3(call);
     audioElement.pause();
} else{audioElement.pause();}
```

Comment: Yes it does work : http://jsfiddle.net/usL1u8ny/

Comment: 2 of the confirms work on my mobile as wellbut the third one which automatically triggers after getting the network data doesnt work.

Comment: I think you may find that it's intentionally deprecated. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52282/why-are-alert-confirm-dialogs-bad-for-mobile-web

Comment: It suggests that your code is not reaching the confirm function in the first place.  If you have backgrounded your web page then it might be causing the issue (i.e, the browser is paused)

Comment: It does in Desktop, is any reason it doesnt in mobile chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Yes. Android chrome does support confirm().**

It is as simple as this to test:

From my android chrome I visited the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm) Try it site.

[image: HERE]

This is the screenshot from my android device.

I found it no different from the desktop chrome.

**2. My suggestion is to debug step by step:**
Why don't you try something obvious like this to test.

```
if(confirm("Answer call?") == true)alert("Inside if");
else alert("Inside else");
```

Most likely, the issue is with call.answer(window.localStream). You may think in this terms or provide more info for us to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does support that. But after a few triggers it will automatically block them if they are in a loop.